# Asp.net application suddenly stopped responding to requests

Tags: vb.net, iis, sql-server-2012, windows-server-2012, asp.net-4.5

Good day, I am a newbie in .net programming and also IIS web deployment configuration.

Currently, I have an asp.net application that runs using Framework 4.5 on IIS. For the first month of having the application deployed on the server, it was running fine and smoothly. However, recently the application had issues whereby the login page would actually load but when the users key in their credentials, the page loading timer would show and it disappears, leaving the user stranded, unable to login.

In addition, the server had undergone security procedures as stated below:

1. Windows Hardening (Using Windows Server 2012)
2. SQL Server Hardening (SQL Server 2012) and port was changed to 8001

Also, the architecture of the application is that:

1. The Application is deployed in **AMLWEB** server
2. The SQL Server Database is in **AMLDB** server

So, the connection actually goes across server and the login authentication is actually authenticated against **Active Directory**.

The screenshot as attached:
[Unhandled exception screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/d377ut6bz9b7gnb/screen.png?dl=0)

When checked on the event viewer, the below warning was seen that may suggest to be contributing to the issue:

```
Event code: 3005 
Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred. 
Event time: 1/18/2015 5:27:15 PM 
Event time (UTC): 1/18/2015 9:27:15 AM 
Event ID: 2ac169fff7284e86b7b0844e5d9ccab1 
Event sequence: 4 
Event occurrence: 1 
Event detail code: 0 

Application information: 
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT/AML-1-130660468323976167 
    Trust level: Full 
    Application Virtual Path: /AML
    Application Path: D:\AML\ 
    Machine name: AMLWEB 

Process information: 
    Process ID: 6756 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: IIS APPPOOL\.NET v4.5 

Exception information: 
    Exception type: InvalidOperationException 
    Exception message: The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.PermissionDemand()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.PermissionDemand(DbConnection outerConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at DBManager.DBManager.OpenConnection(String DBStrConn, Int16 DBType) in C:\Users\TESS-HP003\Desktop\AML\ES_Library\DBManager\DBManager.vb:line 50
   at DBManager.DBManager.ExecuteSQLQuery_ReturnDS(String& ReturnErrorMsg, String SqlString, String DBConnString, Int16 DBType) in C:\Users\TESS-HP003\Desktop\AML\ES_Library\DBManager\DBManager.vb:line 190
   at SQLAdminQueryManager.AdminQueryManager.AdminQueryManager_Staff_Login.Staff_Login_Retreive(cor_staff AppEntity, String DbSQLConnString, String DbType, String& ReturnErrorMsg, Object& ReturnObjDataset, String AccessType) in C:\Users\TESS-HP003\Desktop\AML\ES_Library\SQLAdminQueryManager\AdminQueryManager.vb:line 65
   at Login_page_LDAP_Code.LoginButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)



Request information: 
    Request URL: https://amlweb/AML/Login_page.aspx 
    Request path: /AML/Login_page.aspx 
    User host address: 10.1.67.61 
    User:  
    Is authenticated: False 
    Authentication Type:  
    Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\.NET v4.5 

Thread information: 
    Thread ID: 10 
    Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\.NET v4.5 
    Is impersonating: False 
    Stack trace:    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.PermissionDemand()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.PermissionDemand(DbConnection outerConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at DBManager.DBManager.OpenConnection(String DBStrConn, Int16 DBType) in C:\Users\TESS-HP003\Desktop\AML\ES_Library\DBManager\DBManager.vb:line 50
   at DBManager.DBManager.ExecuteSQLQuery_ReturnDS(String& ReturnErrorMsg, String SqlString, String DBConnString, Int16 DBType) in C:\Users\TESS-HP003\Desktop\AML\ES_Library\DBManager\DBManager.vb:line 190
   at SQLAdminQueryManager.AdminQueryManager.AdminQueryManager_Staff_Login.Staff_Login_Retreive(cor_staff AppEntity, String DbSQLConnString, String DbType, String& ReturnErrorMsg, Object& ReturnObjDataset, String AccessType) in C:\Users\TESS-HP003\Desktop\AML\ES_Library\SQLAdminQueryManager\AdminQueryManager.vb:line 65
   at Login_page_LDAP_Code.LoginButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)


Custom event details:
```

However, the connection string was indeed had been set up properly as below:

Web.config

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="AMLDBConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=AMLDB01, 8001;Initial Catalog=AML_DB;integrated security=true; uid=sa; pwd=p@ssw0rd"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

And it was set up as a global variable as so:

```
GlobalSQLConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("AMLDBConnectionString").ToString
GlobalDBType As Int16 = 1
```

The line which actually executed to connect to the DB:

```
blnReturnValue = objSqlQuery.Staff_Login_Retreive(objBE, GlobalSQLConnString, GlobalDBType, strErrorMsgReturn, returnDS, "S")
```

The method invoked:

```
Public Function Staff_Login_Retreive(ByVal AppEntity As BusinessEntities.cor_staff, _
                                             ByVal DbSQLConnString As String, ByVal DbType As String, _
                                             ByRef ReturnErrorMsg As String, ByRef ReturnObjDataset As Object, _
                                             Optional ByVal AccessType As String = "S") As Boolean
            With AppEntity
                SQlQuery = "SELECT * "
                SQlQuery += " FROM cor_staff "
                SQlQuery += " WHERE cor_staff.cor_userid =N'" & AppEntity.cor_userid & "'"
            End With
            '
            If AccessType.ToUpper = "R" Then
                ReturnObjDataset = ExecuteSQLQuery_ReturnIDR(ReturnErrorMsg, SQlQuery, DbSQLConnString, DbType)
            Else
                ReturnObjDataset = ExecuteSQLQuery_ReturnDS(ReturnErrorMsg, SQlQuery, DbSQLConnString, DbType)
            End If
            '
            If ReturnErrorMsg.Trim.Length = 0 Then
                Return True
            Else
                Return False
            End If
            '
        End Function
```

**Edited**

Since the above code would actually run through and would actually be invoked on this line:

```
ReturnObjDataset = ExecuteSQLQuery_ReturnDS(ReturnErrorMsg, SQlQuery, DbSQLConnString, DbType)
```

The connection would only be opened here:

```
Public Function ExecuteSQLQuery_ReturnDS(ByRef ReturnErrorMsg As String, ByVal SqlString As String, ByVal DBConnString As String, ByVal DBType As Int16) As DataSet
        ReturnErrorMsg = ""
        Dim DS As New DataSet
        '
        If DBType = 1 Then
            Try
                OpenConnection(DBConnString, DBType)
                Dim sqlCmd As New SqlCommand(SqlString, sqlConn)
                sqlCmd.CommandTimeout = 0
                Dim sqlDaAdp As New SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd)
                sqlDaAdp.Fill(DS)
                sqlCmd = Nothing
                sqlDaAdp = Nothing
                CloseConnection(DBType)
                Return DS
            Catch ex As SqlException
                If ex.Number = 18456 Or ex.Number = 4060 Then
                    ReturnErrorMsg = "Database Connection Error >> Error No : " & ex.Number
                Else
                    ReturnErrorMsg = "SQL Statement Error >> Error No : " & ex.Number
                End If
                CloseConnection(DBType)
                Return Nothing
            End Try
        ElseIf DBType = 3 Then
            Try
                OpenConnection(DBConnString, DBType)
                Dim oledbCmd As New OleDbCommand(SqlString, oleDbconn)
                Dim oledbDaAdp As New OleDbDataAdapter(oledbCmd)
                oledbDaAdp.Fill(DS)
                oledbDaAdp = Nothing
                oledbDaAdp = Nothing
                CloseConnection(DBType)
                Return DS
            Catch ex As OleDbException
                If ex.ErrorCode = -2147217887 Then
                    ReturnErrorMsg = "Database Connection Error >> Error Code : " & ex.ErrorCode
                Else
                    ReturnErrorMsg = "SQL Statement Error >> Error Code : " & ex.ErrorCode
                End If
                CloseConnection(DBType)
                Return Nothing
            End Try
        End If
        '
        Return Nothing
        '
    End Function
```

Open connection method:

```
Public Sub OpenConnection(ByVal DBStrConn As String, ByVal DBType As Int16)
        Try
            If DBType = 1 Then
                sqlConn = New SqlConnection(DBStrConn)
                If sqlConn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
                    sqlConn.Open()
                Else
                    sqlConn.Close()
                    sqlConn.Open()
                End If
            ElseIf DBType = 3 Then
                oleDbconn = New OleDbConnection(DBStrConn)
                If oleDbconn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
                    oleDbconn.Open()
                Else
                    oleDbconn.Close()
                    oleDbconn.Open()
                End If
            End If
            '
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw
        End Try

    End Sub
```

**End of edited part**

Does anyone have any idea why does such exception would occur?

So far, I've done the following to actually try to debug this issue:

1. Restart IIS
2. Restart Application Pool
3. Recycle Application Pool (every 12 hours, 8 a.m. and 8 p.m. specifically)
4. Restart SQL Server Service

None of the above worked. But when I actually tried accessing the application from a specific floor in which is the Security Team floor, the application actually starts functioning as usual, and others could actually access the application as well.

Please help, I'm totally going out of my mind about this issue.

Does it have anything to do with my deployment method, iis configuration or programming, I'm willing to listen to suggestions.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Did you open the connection explicitly? The exception looks like you haven't

Comment: Sorry sir, but by how do you mean to open the connection explicitly? I've edited the post accordingly with added codes where the connections are being opened. Thanks.

Comment: Please try the following to get the connection string...

ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("AMLDBConnectionString").ConnectionString

Comment: Sir, does it differ from the above code I included?..
GlobalSQLConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("AMLDBConnectionString").ToString .. Sorry as I am a newbie.

Comment: 1. Your connection string indicates both trusted (integrated security=true) and SQL (uid=sa) authentication. Which one are you using? You can only use one. 2. Your error message is pointing at a VB file on the desktop. Is that where you deployed your web app? In short the server hardening has probably turned on firewalls which in turn means you cannot connect. Remote on to the web server and confirm (using UDL or ODBC) whether or not you can connect to the SQL Server

Comment: Sir @Nick.McDermaid, about your first question, I will look into it and will revert a.s.a.p.
About your second question, this is something I've been wondering as well, the file that the error is pointing to is actually the place whereby I actually published the .net application before deploying the application into the server, would this be the problem?
This issue occurs in a rather weird pattern, whereby it would happen once a week, but when I actually accessed the application from the machine I specified at a certain floor, the application worked like a charm and as normal.

Comment: The Desktop location thing is probably irrelevant for your immediate problem, it is just a 'smell' - something that shouldn't be that way. Does your login page issue happen all the time or does it work sometimes and fail other times? Please clarify. And it's important to log on to the web server and check SQL Server connectivity.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid - integrated security=true, would that not lead to ignoring the other username/password specified in the connection string?

Comment: Sir @Nick.McDermaid, for the first month of having the application deployed in the web server, it worked with no problems. Only recently, to be specific, the application had been deployed since November, only started popping up such problem in the early/mid of December. This what bugs me, how can it actually work and then unconditionally failed. Also, another weird thing is that, when users from various places tried to login into the application, this exception occurs, but when I actually go to a machine at a specific floor, the exception went away, and everyone could access the app afterwards

Comment: @user2260040 , i would definitely look into this matter and would inform if it actually effects the application. Thank you.

Comment: integrated_security=true might ignore that uid, but 1. I've seen examples where it doesn't, and 2. It indicates the programmer doesn't understand the difference, and 3. It introduces some uncertainty to the whole issue and should be resolved. The symptoms you describe indicate that you need to do more tests. Firstly can you connect to the SQL Server and secondly does the application pool recycle (restart) properly when the error occurs.

Comment: Sir @Nick.McDermaid, The connection to the database has no issue cos usually if the connection was unable to be established in cases of having pointed to the wrong DB server, database or wrong credentials, the application would prompt something like "SQL Statement Error >> " as set inside the application. Apart from that about the application pool recycle.. the daily automated ones works fine, but during the error occurs, we actually did manual restarts for the services and still couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Sir @Nick.McDermaid, I would try regarding having the integrated security=true removed but this case would only a rather try and error situation. And I wouldn't know until the application works smoothly. But up to now, it had never given any errors regarding having the credentials ignored or as such. But will take this info into considerations.